# Batch script and get the output value of a found key

Tags: command-line, batch

All works fine in a CMD prompt, but, I need put in a bat file to run, but cannot get the output of the Reg Query cmd, and then run another query from that.

Since what I am looking for is an App ID, and it can change, I need to find the rest of the key, the following in a command prompt gets me what I need:

```
REG Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /F "APP_NAME" /E /S
```

Gives me the needed key such as:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{398E49A0-84CA-43B5-A926-42EF68619E91}
```

From there I can run another command to get the uninstall command:

```
REG Query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{398E49A0-84CA-43B5-A926-42EF68619E91} /V "UninstallString"
```

I have tried what I have been seeing on the site using `for \f token....` but it is not giving me just the first string, even with skip. Nor have I been able to assign it somehow. I need something like:

```
set Full_Key = reg query...
set Uninstall_CMD = Full_Key "/V Uninstallstring"
```

I know there will be only 1 entry, once it is found.

Comment: I do not know what the sub key will be, i need to search for the App ID associated with the app name, if i run the first query with the real name just as it is, i get the subkey. this all works if i do it prompt. This whole thing is over the issue of Dell SupportAssist mem leak issue and have to uninstall through GPO rather than one box at a time. it is starting to cause a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of homework, and digging through my old books, I got this working. Posting code here in case someone needs to uninstall the same app as I need to on a network, or need a starting point.

The main issue I had to solve was finding the App ID, and then get the uninstall string from the registry, since there is no typical uninstall file.

May not be the best looking piece of code, but does work.

```
rem First Check To See If The App Is Even Installed, In My Case, It May Not Be A Dell Box, Or We Already Uninstalled

REG Query %Computer%HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /F "Dell SupportAssist" /E /D /S > NUL
Rem If We have Error, It Is Not There, Bail Out
if errorlevel 1 exit
rem The Key Is Found, So It Must Be Installed, So Get The Full Key, By Searching For The App Name
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('REG Query %Computer%HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /F "Dell SupportAssist" /E /D /S 2^>NUL ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"HKEY_"') DO (
rem Now We Have The Full Key From Above, Grab The Uninstall Command And Run It
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%B IN ('REG Query "%Computer%%%~A" /F UninstallString /V /E ^| FIND /I " UninstallString "') DO %%C% /qn

)
```